# boost::algorithm::contains

Tags: c++, boost, contains

I looked at the template definition and the parameters appear to want iterators across a range and a predicate.  I passed in a vector.begin(), ...end(), and a std::string predicate but still get many compile time errors related a host of boost library items.  Can I see a clear example of the use of boost::algorithm::contains please?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's fairly simple, I guess you are passing iterators when you should be passing containers.

```
  std::string s = "fishing"; 
  std::cout << boost::algorithm::contains(s, "is") << std::endl; 
  std::vector<int> v {1,2,3,5,7,2,7,4,5,8};
  std::vector<int> v2 {5,7,2,7,4};
  std::vector<int> v3 {5,7,2,7,3};
  std::cout << boost::algorithm::contains(v, v2) << std::endl;
  std::cout << boost::algorithm::contains(v, v3) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Yes, I must have misread the template function parameters or misunderstood what to pass in.  I take it then that a range is referring to a container in the STL and not an iterator.  Thank you for this good example.

Comment: @Mushy "Ranges" are actually more than just containers, if you're really interested in that, have a look at the Boost Range 2.0 docs or google for Alexandrescu's boostcon keynote about ranges.